# Запись в таблицу только если данные были изменены

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Можно ли как-нибудь реализовать запрет выполнения `UPDATE` в таблицу, если данные не были изменены?

Например, пользователь заходит на страницу с формой, ничего не меняет в ее полях и нажимает на "Сохранить". В результате это SQL запрос.

У меня в модели используется `after_update_commit` для записи аудита. По сути каждый SQL запрос (конкретно - данные таблицы) пишется в аудит. Хочется как-то избежать хранение подобных "бесполезных" редактирований пользователей.

Comment: *пользователь заходит на страницу с формой, ничего не меняет в ее полях и нажимает на "Сохранить". В результате это SQL запрос* Ну так запоминайте, что было, и сравнивайте с тем, что стало. Средствами формы. И только если нашлись различия - тогда шлите запрос. *Хочется как-то избежать хранение подобных "бесполезных" редактирований пользователей.* У Вас аудит действий или изменений? если второе - отдайте это триггерам, и вопрос решён, а если первое - то Вы сами себе противоречите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
around_update :write_audit

def write_audit
    return unless changed?
    yield
    # Тут по сути after_update
end
```